# Differences between Datastore Entity types fetched from different API

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, airflow, gcloud

here are 2 ways of working with GCP Datastore entities:

#### Option 1 - gcloud client lib

```
from google.cloud import datastore
client = datastore.Client()
...
key = datastore.key.Key(kind, id, project=project_id)
entity = client.get(key)
```

the type of `entity` above is `<class 'google.cloud.datastore.entity.Entity'>`, and the contents looks like

```
<Entity('DemoClass', 1234567890123) {'prop1': 'xxx', 'prop2': 'yyy', ...}>
```

#### Option 2 - REST API

The response of executing a Datastore query with Rest API is a [QueryResultBatch](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/data/rest/v1/projects/runQuery#QueryResultBatch), which contains a list of [EntityResult](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/data/rest/v1/EntityResult), and inside an [EntityResult](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/data/rest/v1/EntityResult) there is an [Entity](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/data/rest/v1/Entity) object.  The type of this entity object is `<class 'dict'>`, and it looks like something like this:

```
{
  "key": {
    {'partitionId': {
       'projectId': 'test_project'
      }, 
     'path': [{'kind': 'DemoClass', 'id': '1234567890123'}]
    }
  },
  "properties": {
    string: {
      object(Value)
    },
    ...
  },
}
```

#### Question

Is there any "built-in" way of converting them back and forth? When I work with `DatastoreHook` in Airflow, since it's based on the Rest API, what I get is the [Entity](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/data/rest/v1/Entity) dict, I can certainly construct a `datastore.key.Key` and re-fetch to get a `google.cloud.datastore.entity.Entity`, but I'm wondering if there's any better, less wasteful way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

The format of `Option 2 - REST API` looks like the `entity_pb2.Entity` format

And it looks like `google.cloud.datastore` has this function:

```
google.cloud.datastore.helpers.entity_from_protobuf
```

https://googleapis.dev/python/datastore/latest/helpers.html#google.cloud.datastore.helpers.entity_from_protobuf

So the final piece of the puzzle is actually transforming the response from `Option 2 - REST API` into an actual instance of `entity_pb2.Entity`

There's this other helper lib which is geared towards entity_pb2
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-datastore/blob/master/python/googledatastore/helper.py

There might be an existing function out there somewhere that can do this, but something like this should do the trick:

```
from google.cloud.proto.datastore.v1 import entity_pb2
from googledatastore import helper

def parse_query_result(result):    
    """Transform a single query result into a `google.cloud.datastore.entity.Entity`"""

    entity = entity_pb2.Entity()
    for path_element in result['key']:
        helper.add_key_path(entity.key, path_element['kind'], path_element['id'])

    for key, value_obj in result['properties'].iteritems():
        name = value_obj.keys()[0]
        value = value_obj[name]
        helper.set_property(entity.properties, name, value)

    return google.cloud.datastore.helpers.entity_from_protobuf(entity)
```